# How deeply nested can constexpr expressions be?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Considering a program is comprised entirely of constexpr functions (which are all capable of being computed at compile-time), is there a limit to how "levels" deep can constexpr functions be called? Could a whole program be computed at compile-time, given the right requisites, by using only constexpr functions?

Comment: The C++ standard does not specify an explicit limit.

Comment: I would imagine the limitation would be determined by the compiler processing the `constexpr` statements (compiler memory, stack overflow, etc) rather than the language itself.

Comment: Regarding the second question, a whole program is not an expression. What do you mean by a program computed at compile-time? Something like `int main() { return 0; }` (which is a program that returns a result computed in compile-time: zero)?

Comment: @AndréSassi: `return 0;` is an artifact, and not even required. Surely you can imagine a program whose sole purpose it is to calculate a single value. That's the type of program the OP is referring to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard *recommends* in Annex B a limit that is at least 512, but a conforming implementation need not comply with the recommendation.

> — Recursive `constexpr` function invocations [512].

Comment: Do you happen to have a list with the implemented limits for the major compilers (GCC/Clang/MSC)?

Comment: @IInspectable For Clang see here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-implementation-limits
For GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html